# How do I best construct a request to return coordinates of tweets

Tags: objective-c

I've been looking for ages with no luck. How do I construct a search query to return tweets within a specific radius of my lat long. I will need to get the coordinates of the returned tweets so that I can plot on a map
Specifically
Do I need to authenticate the request in the 1.1 api?
How do I loop through the tweets to get the coordinates?
Is there a tutorial that may help me?